# Add Infant PassengerDetailsRQ version 3.4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, sabre

I'm using PassengerDetailsRQ version 3.4.0. I try to add SSR for Infant but in response i get a warning **INFANT DETAILS REQUIRED IN SSR - ENTER 4INFT/...**

In version 3.3.0 it still works but in 3.4.0 its not working.

Here my code, please help me fix the issue

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.4.0">
   <PostProcessing xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_4">
      <RedisplayReservation waitInterval="100" />
      <EndTransactionRQ>
         <EndTransaction Ind="true" />
         <Source ReceivedFrom="GDS MF" />
      </EndTransactionRQ>
   </PostProcessing>
   <PriceQuoteInfo xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_4">
      <Link hostedCarrier="true" nameNumber="1.1" record="1" />
      <Link hostedCarrier="true" nameNumber="2.1" record="2" />
      <Link hostedCarrier="true" nameNumber="3.1" record="3" />
   </PriceQuoteInfo>
   <SpecialReqDetails xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_4">
      <SpecialServiceRQ>
         <SpecialServiceInfo>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="1">
               <PersonName DateOfBirth="2016-11-26" Gender="M" NameNumber="2.1">
                  <GivenName>HOANG ANH</GivenName>
                  <Surname>PHAM</Surname>
               </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="1">
               <PersonName DateOfBirth="2018-11-26" Gender="FI" NameNumber="3.1">
                  <GivenName>HOANG TUNG</GivenName>
                  <Surname>PHAM</Surname>
               </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="CHLD">
               <PersonName NameNumber="2.1" />
               <Text>26NOV16</Text>
            </Service>
            <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="INFT">
               <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" />
               <Text>PHAM/HOANG TUNG/26NOV18</Text>
            </Service>
         </SpecialServiceInfo>
      </SpecialServiceRQ>
   </SpecialReqDetails>
   <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_4">
      <AgencyInfo>
         <Address>
            <AddressLine>Ba Dinh</AddressLine>
            <CityName>Hanoi</CityName>
            <CountryCode>VN</CountryCode>
            <PostalCode>100000</PostalCode>
            <VendorPrefs>
               <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
         </Address>
         <Ticketing TicketType="8TL30" />
      </AgencyInfo>
      <CustomerInfo>
         <ContactNumbers>
            <ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" Phone="0366610329" PhoneUseType="B" />
         </ContactNumbers>
         <Email Address="buitrungIT@gmail.com" NameNumber="1.1" />
         <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT">
            <GivenName>VAN THANG</GivenName>
            <Surname>PHAM</Surname>
         </PersonName>
         <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="2.1" PassengerType="CNN">
            <GivenName>HOANG ANH</GivenName>
            <Surname>PHAM</Surname>
         </PersonName>
         <PersonName Infant="true" NameNumber="3.1" PassengerType="INF">
            <GivenName>HOANG TUNG</GivenName>
            <Surname>PHAM</Surname>
         </PersonName>
      </CustomerInfo>
   </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
</PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

please tell me what parameter I'm missing or what should I do to add customer information in the PassengerDetailsRQ too.

Please verify if this request is valid or should I need to add more information to make it right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be sending 3.1 as name reference in the 3DOCS format, I think you should correct that and point to an ADT, as the 3DOCS has to point to the adult taking charge of the infant, like so:

```
   <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="1">
           <PersonName DateOfBirth="2018-11-26" Gender="FI" NameNumber="1.1">
              <GivenName>HOANG TUNG</GivenName>
              <Surname>PHAM</Surname>
           </PersonName>
        </SecureFlight>
```

You also seem to be missing the SecureFlight details for the first passenger. This could be stopping the service from being able to send the 3INFT format, since it creates all of these formats together, concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

In the Secure Flight section, for INFANT, the name number should point to the adult taking charge of the infant. In the request, it is mentioned as 3.1 whereas it should be 1.1. This is needed for infants only and not children. Also looks like the request is missing the SecureFlight details for the first passenger.
Also, if Infant is without seat then for SSR we also need ADT NameNumber and for text, it should be in this format LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME/DATE OF BIRTH.
If Infant is with seat then for SSR we also need ADT NameNumber and for text, it should be in this format LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME/DATEOFBIRTH/OS.